# Homestead wildcard map all subfolders of directory to subdomains automatically

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

How can I configure Homestead to automatically map all subfolders of a certain directory to subdomains?

Here is (part of) my Homestead.yaml:

```
folders:
    - map: c:/code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: pyrocms.192.168.1.199.xip.io
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/pyrocms/public
      schedule: false
    - map: octobercms.192.168.1.199.xip.io
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/octobercms/public
      schedule: false
    - map: coastercms.192.168.1.199.xip.io
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/coastercms/public
      schedule: false
      # plus many other sites here
```

What I *want* to be able to do instead is have just *one* "site" entry in Homestead.yaml that might look something like this:

```
sites:
    - map: *.192.168.1.199.xip.io
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/*/public
      schedule: false
```

**Then, whenever I create a new Laravel project anywhere in `/home/vagrant/Code/`, it would automatically be accessible at the appropriate subdomain.**

How can I achieve this? I vaguely recollect being able to do something like this with symlinks but can't remember how.